# How to implement skip connections from MSG-GAN paper

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement the technique described in the MSG-GAN paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.06048.pdf

[image: MSG-GAN architecture]

But I am having difficulty understanding some things, for example, how are the connections made from the generator to the discriminator? These are Conv2D connections literally? (in that case, how would I insert the real images to train the discriminator?) Or does the discriminator have multiple outputs (one prediction for each resolution and the generator has to optimize the average loss of the resolutions)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How are the connections made from the generator to the discriminator?**

Generator output them and discriminator concatenate them with feature maps from last layer at corresponding input layer.

**These are Conv2D connections literally?**

Those just input tensor with shape like(batch size, W, H, 3), same as ordinary image input.

**Does the discriminator have multiple outputs?**

No, this is end to end training, training with all resolution outputs at same time, otherwise it will just like the Progressive Growing GAN and no reason for concatenate operation at each input layer(beginning of each block) of discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

this is only a partial answer.

I would say that if you had to implement this in keras, and you don't want each model (G and D) to be in one piece, it's actually easier to have them separated and then use tf.GradientTape() to train

**Does the discriminator have multiple outputs?**

yes, if implementing them as separate models, yes there will be multiple inputs and multiple outputs of multiple resolutions, only one of those is the final output.